# AFNetworking json option

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Where should I put the json: body?
I put it in parameters but it does not work.
Help

```
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.upbit.com/v1/orders",
  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
  json: body
};
```

---

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];
[manager POST:@"https://api.upbit.com/v1/orders" parameters:jsonString progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}];
```

Comment: (lldb) po jsonString
{
  "market" : "KRW-BTC",
  "volume" : "1",
  "price" : "1000",
  "ord_type" : "limit",
  "side" : "bid"
}
@KetanOdedra

Comment: `parameters:jsonString` => `parameters:parameters`. Also, you usually don't sent PrettyPrinted JSON, it's useless, it adds spaces, break lines, etc which adds size to your request. You should send a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` in parameters and AFNetworking will do the conversion.